# Tools to evaluate telecommunications link budget

Tags: communication, communication-satellite, simulation

Can you name some of the commercially and non-commercially available tools to evaluate the link budget for a space mission?
Aside Satellite Tool Kit, of course ;)

Comment: We normally avoid questions that are answered by a list that will change with time and is difficult to make complete. Also, it is against policy to list commercial products, as it amounts to a recommendation, and we can't open the door to people using this as a place to advertise. If you can be more specific about what you are trying to do, there may be other ways we can help.

Comment: You can do almost everything in a spreadsheet program and a textbook to reference for equations. The thing that is tricky is when you need have complex 3D relationships that you would like to include, but simple orbits can be done pretty easily. I've done this for a 1 ground station - 1 satellite system including atmospheric effects in about 100 lines of code.

Comment: You can do it all in your favorite spreadsheet program and reference textbook. I was able to do one for a single satellite in orbit and one ground station in 100 lines of equations, including atmospheric effects, antenna patterns, and interference.

Comment: @AndrewW. I'm asking because I'm at that point when a link budget evaluated in a spreadsheet (which I've already created) is not enough to see how the comms will perform

Comment: @kimholder as I already replied to AndrewW, I've already made a preliminary link budget in a spreadsheet; now I'm looking at a tool that enables me to see how the comms will perform during the mission (that is, the ability to include the orbit propagation)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Unfortunately this type of question falls outside the scope of what Stack Exchange is good at. What we can do is create a chat room for you where you can discuss this with users who might be able to help when they are available. I realize it is not an ideal solution, but maybe Andrew at least can discuss it with you further.

Comment: @AndrewW. Anyone who wishes to provide more advice to Alessandro can discuss in this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38643/telecommunications-performance-tools

Comment: @called2voyage well, it's always more than nothing :) I understand that this question is not a regular one